# Url building by @RequestMapping name not working as expected with custom names

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/comments", name = "AdminCommentsController")
@Slf4j
public class CommentsController {

    @Autowired
    private PlaceService placeService;

    @Autowired
    private CommentRepository commentRepository;

    @GetMapping("/awaiting-approval")
    public String listAwaitingApproval(@PageableDefault(size = 50, page = 0) Pageable pageable, Model model) {
        Page<Comment> comments = commentRepository.findByApprovedIsFalseOrApprovedIsNull(pageable);
        model.addAttribute("page", comments);

        return "admin/comments/awaitingApproval";
    }
}
```

And I want to build a URL in view by mapping name like that:

```
<li>
    <a th:href="${#mvc.url('AdminCommentsController#listAwaitingApproval')}" href="add.html">
        Awaiting approval
    </a>
</li>
```

But I am getting an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping mappingName not found:
>   AdminCommentsController#listAwaitingApproval

Removing `name` attribute from type-level `@RequestMapping` will make `CC#listAwaitingApproval` work, but shouldn't it work as well with specified name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html):

> public abstract String name
>
> Assign a name to this mapping. Supported
> at the type level as well as at the method level! When used on both
> levels, a combined name is derived by concatenation with "#" as
> separator.

The key moment is `When used on both levels`

So you should assign name for `@GetMapping` as well and it should start working

Comment: I thought that "both levels" reffers to `@RequestMapping` annotation usage, not `name` parameter. Checked and it works like you described. Thank you.

Comment: You are right. Both levels reffers to `@RequestMapping`, but `@GetMapping` it is the same as `@RequestMapping`

Comment: Hang on, if it would reffer to annotation, than it should work like I described. If it reffers to `name` attribute (like I understand from your point of view) then it should not work, and would work if both names would be set (and that is correct, tested). So it reffers to attribute, not plain annotation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oops, looks like I misunderstood your comment. "It would work if both names would be set" - this is correct.

Comment: Great! Thank you one more time.