# How to reference/build the URL of a (named) Spring Web @RequestMapping on a HTML page using Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, url, mapping, thymeleaf, href

I just started using Spring Web & Thymeleaf for the development of a simple webapplication.
It is going pretty well but so far I am unable to figure out how to prevent duplicate code for the hrefs and various paths/routes.

Example Spring get mapping:

```
...
@GetMapping(path="/hello")
public String hello(){
   return "hello";
}
...
```

First HTML page (index.html) containing href to '/hello', using Thymeleaf:

```
...
<a th:href="@{/hello}">Hello</a>
...
```

Second HTML page (home.html) containing href to '/hello', using Thymeleaf:

```
...
<a th:href="@{/hello}">Hello</a>
...
```

How can I arrange my code so that I don't have to manual update the href on each HTML page when I change the path of a @GetMapping?

Basically I would like to assign the path '/hello' to a variable which i can then reference at each href and getmapping

BR, Kazi

I have been googling for a couple of hours but am unable to find any usable information on my problem.
I have noticed the 'name' attribute of the Spring '@GetMapping' annotation but have no idea if this provides a solution or how it should work together with Thymeleaf.
Also i know that the Django framework for Python based webapplications provides the ability to name routes (using urlpatterns) and reference these from within its templating language. I would expect a similar solution is available for the Spring framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find two solutions:

### Solution 1

Using the capital letters of the controller name in combination with the name of the requestmethod, as described in section 11.1 'Building URIs to controllers' of the official Thymeleaf document [Thymeleaf Tutorial: Thymeleaf + Spring](https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html). The capital letters of the controller name and the requestmethod name are separate by a '#'.

**Important**: The 'name' attribute of the @RequestMapping must not be used else Thymeleaf won't be able to resolve the view!

Note: Possibly this solution is preferred in case path variables or request parameters must be added to the url. (I have not investigated this.)

Example Controller

```
public class ExampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/data")
    public String getData(Model model) { 
        ... 
        return "template" 
    }

    @RequestMapping("/data")
    public String getDataParam(@RequestParam String type) { 
        ... 
        return "template" 
    }
}
```

Example links

```
<a th:href="${(#mvc.url('EC#getData')).build()}">Get Data Param</a>
<a th:href="${(#mvc.url('EC#getDataParam').arg(0,'internal')).build()}">Get 
Data Param</a>
```

### Solution 2

Using the 'name' attribute of the @RequestMapping. As discribe in the following answer to Stackoverflow question [Url building by @RequestMapping name not working as expected with custom names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766797/url-building-by-requestmapping-name-not-working-as-expected-with-custom-names)

The first example only uses the 'name' attribute in the @RequestMapping at the method level.

Example Controller 1

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET, name="home")
    public String index(Model model) { 
        return "index" 
    }  
}
```

Example link 1

```
<a th:href="${(#mvc.url('home')).build()}">Home</a>
```

The second example uses the 'name' attribute in the @RequestMapping at the method level and type level.

Example Controller 2

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/information", name="info")
public class ExampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/organisation", method=RequestMethod.GET, 
    name="org")
    public String contact(Model model) {
        return "organisation" 
    }  
}
```

Example link 2

```
<a th:href="${(#mvc.url('info#org')).build()}">Contact</a>
```